# How to call a React Native function and consume a returned value

Tags: javascript, java, react-native

I would like to call a React Native Javascript function and return some value back to Native java code. So far it seems this is only doable via events. However, I am yet to figure out how to return a value from a React Native event and receive it back in Java.

How can I call a React Native Javascript function from Java and get its return value?

From the documentation, this is how to listen for events :

```
import { NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules } from 'react-native';
...

  componentDidMount() {
    ...
    const eventEmitter = new NativeEventEmitter(NativeModules.ToastExample);
    eventEmitter.addListener('EventReminder', (event) => {
       console.log(event.eventProperty) // "someValue"
    }
    ...
  }
```

Then call them in Java :

```
import com.facebook.react.modules.core.DeviceEventManagerModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableMap;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments;
...
private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext,
                       String eventName,
                       @Nullable WritableMap params) {
  reactContext
      .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
      .emit(eventName, params);
}
...
WritableMap params = Arguments.createMap();
params.putString("eventProperty", "someValue");
...
sendEvent(reactContext, "EventReminder", params);
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it?

Comment: Hi vicke4. It's quite easy. Look it up here : [Android Native Modules](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android)

Comment: Please let me know if manage to call it. If you manage to you could add your approach as an answer and I'll accept it. I'll try posting my answer later on. All the best.